# Codeigniter 4: Crear modelo con dos atributos llave

Tags: codeigniter-4

mi pregunta es simple, tengo una tabla que tiene dos atributos llave, al crear el modelo cómo puedo especificar que ambos lo son, como ejemplo son idp e idm

class PubasignaModel extends Model
{

```
protected $table                = 'pubasigna';
protected $primaryKey           = '????????';
.
.
.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Si está preguntando cómo configurar Model :: primaryKey para admitir una clave primaria de varias columnas. La respuesta es: no puedes. El valor asignado a Model :: primaryKey debe ser el nombre de una sola columna.

Sin embargo, la columna utilizada no necesita ser la clave PRIMARIA real para la tabla. La propiedad puede usar cualquier columna, pero esa columna debe contener valores únicos e idealmente estar indexada.